# Асинхронный клиент веб-службы ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, веб-служба, асинхронность

Всем здравствуйте. Ну и так как я здесь, я в тупике и прошу вашей помощи.
Есть Веб-сервис, который что-то там себе делает. И есть клиент с асинхронным вызовом метода этого веб-сервиса:

```
using System;  
using System.Collections.Generic;  
using System.ComponentModel;  
using System.Data;  
using System.Drawing;  
using System.Linq;  
using System.Text;  
using System.Windows.Forms;  
using Service5WinForm.localhost;

namespace Service5WinForm
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public delegate string DsmDelegate(string name);

        private void HelloWorldCompleted(object sender,
                                 HelloWorldCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            button1.Enabled = true;
            string response = (string)e.Result;
            textBox2.Text = response;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//асинхронный
        {
            Service1 proxy = new Service1();
            string name = this.textBox1.Text;
            button1.Enabled = false;

            proxy.HelloWorldCompleted += new HelloWorldCompletedEventHandler(this.HelloWorldCompleted);
            proxy.HelloWorldAsync(textBox1.Text);
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //???
        }
    }
}
```

Нужно переделать его следующим образом. По нажатию на `Батон1` на сервис посылается запрос с какими-нибудь данными. В это время `Баттон3` становится неактивным(Enabled = `false`). Так как вызов асинхронный, клиент не ждет ответа, а продолжает чем-то там своим заниматься, ИИИ! каким-то макаром клиент должен получить сообщение о том, что веб-служба закончила свою работу, перевести `Батон3` в активное состояние и только при нажатии на `Батон3`, получить в Веб-сервиса получившиеся данные. Заранее огромное спасибо! Мозг кипит.

Comment: @vein, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: Да в том-то и дело, господин Гордеев, что я даже не знаю как к этому заданию подступиться и с чего начать.(

Comment: Написал веб-сервис, клиент, а что дальше со всем этим делать ума не приложу.

Comment: Не зная возможностей ASP, не могу сказать готовое решение.

Общая идея:

По нажатию Кнопки1, шлется запрос на сервер. На сервере запускается обработчик, который создает отдельный поток (в котором и идет вся работа), а клиенту возвращает "ок, я все запустил", и какой-то токен.

Когда поток завершает работу, он присваивает токену статус - готов. Это может быть запись в БД, файл, или элемент статической коллекции.

Клиент регулярно пинает сервер, запросами "ну, токен такой-то, уже готов?". Елси получает ответ нет, то ждет пару сенкунд и пинает снова. Если да, то делает Кнопку3 активной)

Comment: На Java-сервлетах это абсолютно рабочее решение.

Answer (score 1):

1. Это не асп, а винформс
2. Задача странная и уже почти реализована в текущем коде
3. Посылается асинхронный запрос на сервер, ответ на который прийдет в обработчик события 'Completed' (который уже реализован), причем сразу с ответом прийдут и данные (в параметре, если они предусмотрены интерфейсом сервиса)! И далее вы активируете нужные кнопки (в вопросе пишите про баттон3, а дизейблите баттон1). Странность в том, что на данном этапе у вас УЖЕ есть данные, полученные в виде ответа от сервиса и вы их уже можете использовать, зачем надо дополнительный баттон3 я не понимаю. Ну даже если так, то сохраните полученные данные в локальную переменную формы и активируйте баттон3, при нажатии на который работайте с данными из переменной, которые пришли раньше из сервиса.

ПС - постоянно "пинать" сервис и спрашивать его, не обновилось ли состояние чего-либо не самый удачный вариант, хотя и рабочий (спам сервиса-сервера запросами). Не могу ничего сказать насчет сервлетов, но в WCF имеются виды биндингов (netTcp, dual, возможно еще какие-то поддерживают) для двунаправленных взаимодействий.

Comment: Никто ж не говорит пинать постоянно. Раз в минуту и ждать - например. Речь идет-то об НТТР (веб-службы ASP.Net).